# log4.net does not write until Windows Service Stops

Tags: c#, windows-services, log4net

I am using log4.net in my Windows Service for logging. 
Here is my config;

```
 <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="MyApp.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100000KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <immediateFlush value="true" />
</appender>
```

for some reason it does not write into file until I stop the service. Is there a sort of buffering is happening? Once I stop the service all pending logs are getting written.

What would be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, are you **sure** it actually works at all?

My version of log4net (version 1.2.11) requires a **Layout** (otherwise nothing gets logged) and does not have a **BufferSize** property (but that doesn't stop it working)

Also, **immediateFlush** should default to true, so isn't needed.

The following works for me.

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="MyApp.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100000KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Yes, it definitely works. I have layout as well, just removed it as brevity. For some reason it flushes all the logged statements on service stops.

Comment: Is it possible it is a problem with the program you are using to look at the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my windows service, which only wrote to the log when the Service was stopped.

My initial thought was this feels like some sort of locking issue, either in the .Net code or on the file itself and by stopping the windows service, it removes the lock and allows the write to complete.

Having said that, I noticed that changing the User Account under which the Windows Service ran, to one with higher privileges, made it update immediately, rather than only on Service Stop.

I changed it from Local System to Administrator and it fixed the problems. Of course, **running as Administrator isn't recommended**, but it may at least help you to diagnosis if the problem is related to Profile/Permissions.

I still haven't figured out the root cause of this yet...